# Feynman rules of Non-Abelian gauge fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, interactions

The Lagrangian of Non-Abelian field is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}[\text{quadratic term} + 2gf^{abc}A_{\mu}^{b}A_{\nu}^{c}(\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu a}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu a})+ \text{quartic term})]
\end{equation}
The cubic and quartic terms gives the couplings of gauge field itself. The 3-vertice is:
\begin{equation}
-2gf^{abc}\left[(r_{\mu}-q_{\mu})g_{\nu\rho}+(p_{\nu}-r_{\nu})g_{\mu\rho}+(q_{\mu}-p_{\mu})g_{\mu\nu}\right]
\end{equation}

It seems that most of the QFT textbooks simply give this vertice by analogizing the Feynman rules of other theory like QED and directly writing it out from the diagram of the 3-vertice. I'm wondering how to derive this vertice by normal procedure? For example, we insert a sourse $J_{\mu}$, the path integral is:
\begin{equation}
Z[J]=\exp\left[i\int\mathcal{L}_{int}\left(\frac{1}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J^{\mu}}\right) \,dx\right]Z_0[J]
\end{equation}
$\mathcal{L}_{int}$ is the cubic term and $Z_0$ is the free part. I have tried to do this as the procedure of QED, but the result is not what we want. Can this vertice be rigorously worked out like that?

Comment: Yes, you can derive the cuibc vertex for Yang-Mills in exactly the same way you can derive the cubic vertex for any other theory. If you like path integrals, then that's certainly a valid approach.

Comment: I believe Sidney Coleman's book discusses this Feynman rule in more detail than most other books. It might be interesting to check it out

Comment: @Andrew Thanks a lot！I‘ve convinced that this procedure is valid but extremely hard to work out.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks a lot! Coleman’s book is useful and interested in many topics. Appreciate your recommendation!